# 500 Error when using method populate in Express and Mongo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I cannot fetch users data from Mongo when I use populate() method for posts of users.

```
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
User.find()
.populate("posts")
.exec()
.then((users) => {
  res.json({ users });
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Mongo Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const Post = require("../models/Post");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    requied: true
  },
  userimg: {
    type: String
  },
  followers: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  following: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  posts: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Post"
    }
  ],
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

When I remove .populate("posts") than I get 200 Success status and users data but without popoulation of referred posts from the posts collection.

Comment: Also post the error.

Comment: Can you show your Mongoose schema?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Add that here.

Comment: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post".
[0] Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
But I have: module.exports = Post = mongoose.model("posts", postSchema);

Comment: Change this mongoose.model("users", UserSchema) to mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)

Comment: It's not the schema User schema problem, becasuse fetching when login or register is working good, and fetch without populate also works

Comment: Can you try storing the result in a variable and then return it? `const users = User.find().populate("posts").exec();`

Answer (score 0):

So i'll be doing a little modification to your model file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Post = require("../models/Post");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    requied: true
  },
  userimg: {
    type: String
  },
  followers: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  following: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  posts: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post"
    }
  ],
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Can you change your exec() to execPopulate()

```
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
User.find()
.populate("posts")
.execPopulate()
.then((users) => {
  res.json({ users });
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I found the error:
ref: "posts" instead of ref: "Post"
ref: "users" instead of ref: "User"